# How can Slider auto selected second dots instead of the first dots React Slick

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

My setting:

```
const settings= {
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
        prevArrow: <PrevArrow />,
        dotsClass: "slick-dots mb-9"
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `initialSlide:1` in your settings object

you can check more here on API's doc by React Slick
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api#initialSlide